# Subversion: How could I automatically update a large list of working copies?

Tags: sync, script, svn

I often need to sync projects between the notebook and the
subversion server at
home.

I do it by using the IDE, which is annoying.
*(I have to start it, open all projects because I don't remember on which projects
changes were made, update them all, close the unnecessary ones, ...)*

Are there some tools out there to update many projects automatically (perhaps just a script)?

What would happen on repository-vs-localcopy conflicts?

Comment: whats your environment/os?

Comment: OS is linux, but I would prefer a multiplatfom solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could easily create a script for this using the svn update command line. in case of conflicts it will pause and wait for your input as to how to resolve the conflict. You can also try svn help update to see the switches you can pass along to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a script it is easy with DonationCoder's [Drag and Drop Robot](http://www.donationcoder.com/Software/Mouser/dragdrop/index.html) You'd just create a list of folders by dragging them onto the program and run the svn up command for each of them. (In theory, I haven't used the program)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a script if you have svn client installed locally. The script would look something like this: `svn update C:\SourceFolder` for each folder.